# Is there a nifty way to represent the solution set of a series of equations that are symmetrical using set theoretic notation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

So I had two equations on two variables that were symmetrical. There were two possible solutions, let's call them $a$ and $b$ and so the solution set was $\{(a, b), (b, a)\}$, since the first variable could be any one of the solutions and then the second variable would have to be the other one. I was thinking of representing the solution set as $\{a, b\}^2$ but then I realized this would include ordered pairs such as $(a, a)$ or $(b, b)$ which are not a solution. In other words I want to express the set of ordered n-tuples without repetition.

Of course this could be extended to a series of equations with three variables and three solutions $a, b, c$ in which case I'd like to express the set $\{(a, b, c), (a, c, b), (b, a, c), (b, c, a), (c, a, b), (c, b, a)\}$.

So is there some sort of standard way of representing this using set theoretic notation? Thanks!

Comment: One idea is to enumerate your solutions, i.e., take $x_1,\dots,x_n$ your solutions Obviously this enumeration has no repetitions. Next, the set that your are looking for is $$A=\{(x_{i_1},x_{i_2},\dots,x_{i_n}) : \forall k\in\{1,\dots,n \}, i_k\in\{ 1,\dots,n\} \ \text{and if} \ j\neq k, i_j\neq i_k\}$$

Comment: @CarlosJiménez You could say $A = \{(x_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, x_{\sigma(n)}): \sigma \in S_n\}$, where $S_n$ denotes the permutations of $\{1, \ldots, n\}$.

Comment: $$\cup_{\rm cyclic}\{(a,b,c)\}$$